# Javascript const object syntax - what is this doing? (using in a Vue script)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What is the following statement doing, and why use const vs var?

```
const { SearchIcon } = myApp.icons;
```

For context, I am learning Vue and new to Javascript. I saw this in an example. The SearchIcon is an icon that is being imported from heroicons, MyApp.icons is being defined in a different script file like this:

```
window.MyApp = {
    app: null,
    icons: {},
...
```

Comment: This syntax is called `destructuring`.  You can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring

Comment: it's a shorthand for `const SarchIcon = myApp.icons.SearchIcon;`

Comment: In relation to: "why use const vs var". In Short, `const` is block-scoped and can't be reassigned. Since ES6 you should always consider using `let` and `const` instead of `var`

Here is a longer explanation about the differences between const, let and var: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your issue is that you're storing MyApp under window, but then trying to access it directly. You've also got a capital M in the definition, and a lowercase when your accessing it.

Here's a working example:

```js
window.MyApp = {
  app: null,
  icons: {
    SearchIcon : 'Hello!'
  },
};

const { SearchIcon } = window.MyApp.icons;

console.log(SearchIcon);
```

For more info, see the docs on **[object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)**.

Hope that helps :)